# create labeledpoint from mongodb using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to  create labeledpoint from mongodb using python,

I already tried to do that with a csv file instead of mongodb
here is the code of function that return the labeledpoint

```
def createLabeledPoints(fields):
  q1 = int(fields[0])
  q2 = int(fields[1])
  result = int(fields[38])
  return LabeledPoint(result, array([q1, q2, q3))
```

this code works for me with csv file

and I get my collection from mongodb as a pandas dataframe using the code below

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db1 = client.newumc
collection1 = db.data_classification
rawData1 = DataFrame(list(collection.find({})))
```

and I get each field using the code below

```
field_for_test = collection.find({}, {'field_from_mongodb':1,'_id':0})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by using

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("myApp") \
.config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/newumc.classification_data") \
.config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/newumc.classification_data") \
.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
field1 = df[1]
field2 = df[2]
```